# Nested search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I have an current_user that is an advisor and has many projects

```
 has_many :advisorizations, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :projects, :through => :advisorizations
```

Each project has many users;

```
 has_many :projectizations, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :users, :through => :projectizations
```

Now I want to search amongst curren_users users, ie. the users that are users to projects where the current_user is an advisor.

```
current_user.projects.users
```

gives an error like "undefined method `users' for #

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll should be able to achieve that by adding to your advisors class:

```
has_many :advisorizations, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :projects, :through => :advisorizations
has_many :projectizations, :through => :projects
has_many :users, :through => :projectizations
```

Then you should be able to do `current_user.users` though that might be confusing

Comment: This gives an "undefined method `chain' for nil:NilClass". FYI the user and advisor class is the same..

Comment: Where is the undefined method?  In the view?

Comment: In the controller @ current_user.users line

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace

Comment: undefined method `chain' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #13):
11
12
13
14
15
16
          
    
    
      @users = current_user.users
    end
  end

Comment: I figure it out, i was lacking a has_many variant, your code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @users = []   
 current_user.projects.each{|project| @users << project.users }
```

Comment: This only gives an array of projects (?)

Comment: you will get the users inside the {}. project.users => `users that are users to projects where the current_user is an advisor`

Comment: how do I get them all in a @users variable?

Comment: this still only returns the two projects